# What is that component alimenting a motor?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm building a mini backyard forge and need some air flow. I took apart an old hairdryer to remove the heating coil (to prevent it from overheating over long usage).
I found this component inside and I struggle to identify it.

[image: mysterious electronic component]

What is that ?
Does removing the heating coil possible ? I recon it also act as a resistance, and I'm not sure what would append without it.

Here a crude schematics of the electronics:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5xUTs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Diode bridge = Graetz bridge. V1 is AC, there is no (+) and (-)

Comment: I think you've got the schematic wrong, because the diode bridge and the motor and one of the resistors (no label!) are shorted out.

Comment: You are certainly right. I have very basic electronic understanding, nothing more. My goal was just to show the overall layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a rectifier.

It converts AC to DC.

Mind you, there are better motor/fan combinations available to force air into your forge than a hairdryer.

One thing to note is that you will probably find it is only designed for short time use (5 or 10 minutes) and not an extended use.

Comment: What would you recommend instead of a hairdyer ? I'm aiming for something easy to find and unexpensive.
What's the risk on extended use ?

Comment: How about a car blower motor? even available with 3 or 4 speeds if you get the wiring and switch, and cheap from a scrap yard. And it shifts more air...

Comment: I guess I would need some converter to plug into wall sockets. Would that be easy to find ?

Comment: Or a furnace blower motor.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica one can find those at the scrap yard as well, or an organ blower etc just need to know what one is looking at...

Answer (score 0):

That component is a bridge rectifier. AC voltage across the ~ & ~ terminals is converted to DC across the + & - terminals.

The heating coil drops the mains voltage from 230V AC to around 12V AC which is converted to DC by the bridge rectifier.

The motor may be rated at around 12V DC.

You may remove only the heating coil and run it with a 12V AC supply or remove the heating coil as well as the bridge rectifier and run it with a 12V DC supply.

You could also vary the 12V AC or 12V DC supply to adjust the air flow.

Comment: Can I find a 230V AC to 12V DC converter at reasonable price ?

Comment: @GMartigny what is "reasonable"? How about a simple battery charger?

Comment: @SolarMike If that could work why not. I guess my scrapyard grocery list just got bigger.

Comment: The cheaper option would be to keep the bridge rectifier and feed 12V AC using a 230/12V step down transformer. One with taps at 6V and 9V would make it possible to run it at lower speeds.

Comment: A diode in series with the 12V AC would also lower the speed. It could be bypassed by a switch when the higher speed is required. This feature may already exist in the hair dryer!